# Reversing a nested tuple in Python using the function reversed

Tags: python

I have a tuple and would like to reverse it in Python.

The tuple looks like this : `(2, (4, (1, (10, None))))`.

I tried reversing in Python by:

```
a = (2, (4, (1, (10, None))))
b = reversed(a)
```

It returns me this:

```
<reversed object at 0x02C73270>
```

How do I get the reverse of `a`? Or must I write a function to do this?

The result should look like this:

```
((((None, 10), 1), 4), 2)
```

Comment: What do you expect the reversal result to look like?

Comment: Why do you want the None with the 2 now?

Comment: the elements change position but none stays there..

Comment: So it seems, but by which rule do you tear the tuple `10, None` into pieces?

Comment: Each two-tuple is treated as a cons cell of a singly linked list with `None` as the end of the list (`nil` in Lisp terminolgy), and that linked list is reversed. Everything else is an implementation detail and up to the individual answer ;) Correct me if I'm wrong, lakesh.

Comment: It's not very logical.  I was expecting you wanted `((((None, 10), 1), 4), 2)`

Comment: Apologies, it is ((((None, 10), 1), 4), 2)...

Comment: Given that tuples are intended to be a data structure in which the order of elements is important (and therefore usually fixed), are you sure you don't want to just use a list for this?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor -- How is a list any different?  They have an order of elements as well ... The only thing different is that you can mutate the list in place, but I can't really see why you would want to do that ... (or how that would make it much easier).

Comment: @mgilson: You're right, I should have said "in which the structure of elements is important". Tuples are a structured data type, lists are an ordered one. The very fact you have to coerce a tuple into a mutable type before modifying it should be a strong hint that you shouldn't use it for such a purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def my_reverser(x):
  try:
    x_ = x[::-1]
  except TypeError:
    return x
  else:
    return x if len(x) == 1 else tuple(my_reverser(e) for e in x_)
```

Comment: I like this one -- Just so long as you don't have any strings contained in the tuple ...

Answer (score 3):

Try this deep-reverse function:

```
def deep_reverse(t):
    return tuple(deep_reverse(x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else x 
                 for x in reversed(t))
```

This will handle arbitrarily nested tuples, not just two-tuples.

Comment: What about a `isinstance(x, collections.Sequence)` to cover lists too?

Comment: @PierreGM: In that case, he would change lists into tuples while reversing them. The question was exclusively about tuples, so I would avoid adding this extra complexity at this point.

Comment: nice .. this is better than my one.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed), the `reversed` function returns an iterator (hence the `<reversed at ...>`). If you want to get a list or a tuple out of it, just use `list(reversed(...))` or `tuple(reversed(...))`.

However, it's only part of our problem: you'll be reversing the initial object `(2, (...))` as `(...,2)`, while the `...` stays the same. You have to implement a *recursive* reverse: if one element of your input tuple is an iterable, you need to reverse it to.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to do this with `reversed`, sorry.  But a simple recursive function would return what you want:

```
def reversedLinkedTuple(t):
  if t is None:
    return t
  a, b = t
  return reversedLinkedTuple(b), a
```

`reversed` is usable only on reversible iterable objects like lists, tuples and the like.  What you are using (a linked list) isn't iterable in the sense of the Python built-in `iter`.

You could write a wrapping class for your linked list which implements this and then offers a reverse iterator, but I think that would be overkill and would not really suit your needs.

Comment: `reversed` makes a whole lot of sense if you're not guaranteed that you're always dealing with a 2-tuple.

Comment: Sure, but this case looks a lot like a linked list to me.  Those are always two-tuples.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't understand the rational of using nested tuples as a linked list.  `tuple` are immutable, so you can't add anything to your linked list once you've set it up, you can't delete anything (at least, not without creating an entire new list) ...

Comment: Makes perfect sense in case you need an immutable value of an existing list (e.g. done with lists instead of tuples), maybe to use it as a dictionary key.

Comment: Well, makes sense, not perfect sense.  But anyway, that's what the asker had.  And linked lists can of course make sense even if they are const.

Comment: Maybe I haven't taken enough CS courses -- but a constant linked list seems like it's just a waste (why not use an array?).  Of course, that said, I don't really see a whole lot of a point to a linked list in python anyway as I don't see what you gain over the builtin `list` type, so perhaps (hopefully?) this is just academic anyway ...

Comment: The interface of a linked list is quite different from a list or a tuple.  If a lib is always using linked lists as a usual data structure, it might make sense to return a const value also as a linked list; in this case it could be made up of two-tuples instead of lists of size two.  But we are drifting.  Given enough fantasy you nearly always find a use-case for abstruse given things.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reverse(x):
    while x >= 0:
        print(x)

x = x = 1
reverse(x)
```